# Logarithmic y-axis and restrict y to domain fails

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to plot data with a logarithmic y-axis and restricting the y-data to a specified domain, but compilation fails for a reason I don't understand. This is the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymode=log, restrict y to domain=1:6]
\addplot coordinates {(0, 1.1e1) (1, 1.7e3) (2, 0.0e0) (2, 3.4e7) (4, 8.1e5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Running it results in an error message:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   i
l.6 ..., 1.7e3) (2, 0.0e0) (2, 3.4e7) (4, 8.1e5)};
```

According to the `pgfplots` manual for version 1.5.1 (29 December 2011), page 272 (about restrict x/y/z to domain), *For logarithmic axes, min and max are logs of the respective values*. If I disable either the logarithmic y-axis or the domain-restriction, the code runs successfully and output is as expected (but not as desired).

Software versions:

- `pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011) (format=pdflatex 2012.5.30)`
- `pgfplots 2011/12/29 v1.5.1 (git show 1.5.1-4-g53e640f )`
- `tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)`.

What's going on? What am I doing wrong? Or is this a bug?

Comment: That does indeed seem like a bug, you might want to file a report on the pgfplots sourceforge site. As a workaround, you can use `restrict expr to domain={y}{0:1e6}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a direct answer however it might help to get what you want to do. I also don't know why it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[restrict expr to domain={y}{10:1e6},unbounded coords=discard]
\addplot coordinates {(0, 1.1e1) (1, 1.7e3) (2, 1.0e0) (2, 3.4e7) (4, 8.1e5)};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you remove the `unbounded coords=discard` it is set to `jump`.

[image]
[image]