# pgfplots and logscale not plotting below 10E0

Tags: pgfplots

**EDIT about duplicate**

This question is not a duplicate of [Logarithmic y-axis and restrict y to domain fails](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58617/logarithmic-y-axis-and-restrict-y-to-domain-fails) as suggested. Contrary to this question, compilation does not fail. Furthermore, in the indicated post, the accepted answer states "I also don't know why it doesn't work." which is actually the question I would like an answer to.

Why does the MWE does not plot the first point?

**EDIT:**
Removing the line `restrict y to domain=1E-5:1E4` solves the problem but I would like to understand why.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots} % To produce graphs within tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-0,
            xmax=7,
            ymode=log,
            restrict y to domain=1E-5:1E4,
            ymin=1E-5,
            ymax=1E4]
            
            \addplot coordinates {(0,1E-5) (3,1E1) (7,1E4)};
                    
        \end{axis}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```